# DOS command to list all virtual directories in IIS 6

Tags: iis-6, cmd, virtual-directory, sites, adsutil.vbs

I'm looking for a DOS command to list all sites and virtual directories in IIS 6 under Windows 2003.  I know there are ways to do this using [Powershell / WMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3575442/getting-all-virtual-directories-for-a-iis6-web-site-using-wmi), [VBS](http://anyrest.wordpress.com/2010/02/10/how-to-list-all-websites-in-iis/), [C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3938467/list-all-virtual-directories-in-iis-5-6-and-7), etc.  But all I want is a quick and dirty, no-fuss way to do it from DOS, without the need to create any new files on the Webserver.

EDIT: While researching for this question I managed to come up with a one-liner that does it, but please do suggest an alternative if you have a more elegant solution that fits the criteria above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what I came up with:

```
@FOR /F "delims=[]" %A IN ('@cscript //nologo %SystemDrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs ENUM /P /w3svc') DO @FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=2 %B IN ('@cscript //nologo %SystemDrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs GET %A/ServerComment') DO @FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=2 %C IN ('@cscript %SystemDrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs //nologo GET %A/Root/Path') DO @ECHO %A %B "%C"
```

The command outputs a list of virtual directory ID's, along with the "friendly name" and path for each, e.g.:

```
/w3svc/1 Default Web Site "c:\inetpub\wwwroot"
/w3svc/1236224994 FunWidgets "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\FunWidgets"
/w3svc/1359392326 JimSmith.com "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\JimSmith"
/w3svc/1835917338 BouncyToys "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\bouncytoys"
/w3svc/198968327 AvalonWest "C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\AvWest"
```

If you want to pipe the output to a text file, first make sure it doesn't exist, then append `>> filename.txt` to the command above.  (e.g.: `DEL sites.txt & ... >> sites.txt`)

Here's a breakdown of how the admittedly convoluted command works:

1. `@` is prefixed to every statement to avoid echoing the statement itself, which would pollute the output.
2. `@FOR /F "delims=[]" %A IN ('@cscript //nologo %SystemDrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs ENUM /P /w3svc') DO`

   Invokes [AdsUtil.vbs](https://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d3df4bc9-0954-459a-b5e6-7a8bc462960c.mspx?mfr=true), which is installed with IIS6 (and reads the [metabase](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/a0ea8e51-fb2a-4e80-9d5a-7fe3ae246570.mspx?mfr=true) on our behalf).

   - The `ENUM /P /w3svc` parameter tells it to spit out a list of all sites and virtual directory ID's starting at the root node.
   - The [nologo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525006%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) switch suppresses the usual CScript copyright preamble, to render only the output we're interested in.  A double-backslash is used to escape the slash character, since we're inside a string.
   - The output of the portion in single quotes resembles the following:

     ```
     [/w3svc/1]
     [/w3svc/1236224994]
     [/w3svc/1359392326]
     [/w3svc/1835917338]
     [/w3svc/198968327]
     [/w3svc/AppPools]
     [/w3svc/Filters]
     [/w3svc/Info]
     ```

   This is passed into `FOR /F`, which loops through each line.  `delims=[]` tells FOR to treat square brackets as delimiters.  Everything after the `DO` will be executed once for each line, with the `%A` variable set to whatever is between the square brackets.  (If this was a batch file you'd use `%%A` instead).
3. `@FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=2 %B IN ('@cscript //nologo %SystemDrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs //nologo GET %A/ServerComment') DO`

   This second FOR block runs AdsUtil with the `GET` parameter to retrieve the ServerComment property for the given site / virtual directory.  This is the human-friendly name as seen in IIS.  Unfortunately the output is a bit trickier to parse.  e.g. For `/w3svc/1` you get back:

   ```
   ServerComment                   : (STRING) "Default Web Site"
   ```

   The [careting trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13217838/589059) parses out the text between the quotes.

   Note that nodes we aren't interested (AppPools, Filters and Info) don't have the ServerComment property, and give a result devoid of quotes, e.g.:

   ```
   The path requested could not be found.
   ErrNumber: -2147024893 (0x80070003)
   Error Trying To GET the Object (GetObject Failed): w3svc/Filters
   ```

   Thus the remaining portion of the command line is not invoked for them.
4. `@FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=2 %C IN ('@cscript %SystemDrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs //nologo GET %A/Root/Path') DO @ECHO %A %B "%C"`

   This final FOR retrieves the physical path, then outputs all three pieces of parsed information to the console.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.  This isn't searching recursively for me.  It only lists 'Default Web Site'.  Is there a path somewhere I need to change?  I'm testing this locally.

Comment: @jmosesman: In IIS, is the ServerComment field missing on your subnodes? If so, try it without the filter, i.e: `@FOR /F "delims=[]" %A IN ('@cscript //nologo %SystemDrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs ENUM /P /w3svc') DO @FOR /F delims^=^"^ tokens^=2 %C IN ('@cscript %SystemDrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs //nologo GET %A/Root/Path') DO @ECHO %A "%C"`. If that doesn't work, try step 2 in isolation: `@FOR /F "delims=[]" %A IN ('@cscript //nologo %SystemDrive%\Inetpub\AdminScripts\adsutil.vbs ENUM /P /w3svc') DO @echo %A`.  If still no joy, revert to non-DOS techniques I hyperlinked.