# Retrieve names of all sites on a webserver

Tags: iis, webserver

Is there anyway that I could get names of all sites hosted on a IIS web server, to a text file?

Any command or any alternative?

Tried googling but couldnt find anything related.

Comment: See the answer here..
browse to 
http://serverfault.com/questions/573917/retrieve-names-of-all-sites-on-a-webserver

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a command:

```
appcmd list site
```

This will give you a list of all sites, similar to the (graphical) IIS Management view. You can of course send the output to a text file:

```
appcmd list site > mysites.txt
```

Comment: I dont think it supports in IIS6..

I have my os win server 2003 with IIS6

Answer (score 0):

In IIS6 you can use adsutils. The enum parameter should do the job.

```
Cscript.exe adsutil.vbs ENUM /P W3SVC
```

Check out these Posts: [MS Documentation](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d3df4bc9-0954-459a-b5e6-7a8bc462960c.mspx?mfr=true), [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13218046/dos-command-to-list-all-virtual-directories-in-iis-6)